# Edit URL, Google Forms

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

Is it possible to get the edit URL of Google Forms if you are not sure of the form response number? For example, I have 2,000 forms submitted and I would like to generate the edit links for them now but I think the responses are not in any systematic order.

Also, some of the responses stored in spreadsheet that were either duplicates or invalid have been deleted.

Please can anyone help with this query or just point me in the right direction.

Comment: "...just point me in the right direction":  The Forms Service method of Google Apps Script is `geteditresponseurl`. Search for questions on this site and on [so] about it, then make your question more specific.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. :-) I have seen and used this before but right now I  have responses deleted in the corresponding google sheet but not in actual google forms responses making it difficult to match it. And I can't un link the form from the spreadsheet so was wondering if I get find some way without having to specify the response number.

Comment: I will expand my question further with example